# Google spreadsheet: Show 2 formulas or more in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I just want to know if there's any way to show 2 or more formula values in the same cell.

P.E.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1+A2)
=ARRAYFORMULA(B1+B2)
=ARRAYFORMULA(C1+C2)


Reason: I want to make a center-flooding dashboard with 2 columns by merging cells and using ctrl+enter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one formula per cell, but that formula can consist of different 'parts' that can be joined together. Maybe this formula

```
=A1+A2&char(10)&B1+B2&char(10)&C1+C2
```

will output what you try to achieve with your present example?

Comment: basically did the same thing and included this particular formula as well - [examples](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17pcpFmEj6dEa4917tXxoZVlQz9zmLuxzJ8HByn3rId4/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Great. That's what I've been looking for :)
btw, what's the (10) for?

Comment: char(10) is a line break (move to a new line in the same cell).